# How do I layout circles into a square grid?

Tags: d3.js

I have used D3's [pack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout) to create a cluster of circles, as in A. Should I use another type of layout, or something else, to organise my circles into a square grid (like a table of circles), as in B?

[image]

If I were to try this without any pre-built D3 magic, I guess I would need to iterate through my dataset and calculate how many circles I can fit on a row (determined by the width of the SVG element with some padding accounted for). To calculate the row's height I need to know the height of the largest circle in the row. I would also need to add some padding to each circle - and also pad the rows too.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://bl.ocks.org/herrstucki/5684816)?

Comment: @Mark unfortunately the link is dead.